# How to add missing kernel headers in Banana PI M2 Zero to build kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

First and foremost I have little experience with custom built hardware. So far I've only designed Linux kernel modules on complete systems out of the box, so this may be a silly problem, but I can't solve it.

I have a Banana PI M2 Zero with a minimal Linux 5.6.0-rx5+ kernel based Ubuntu. I want to create a driver for the ADS1294 SPI analog front-end, so I've started with the most basic kernel file:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init test_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "TEST: starting...");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "TEST: stopping...");
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);
```

with the Makefile:

```
obj-m := test_mod.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

After executing `make all`, the system states that `make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.6.0-rc5+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.`.

If I list the content of `/lib/modules/5.6.0-rc5+/` I get: `build  kernel  modules.alias  modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.builtin.modinfo  modules.dep  modules.dep.bin  modules.devname  modules.order  modules.softdep  modules.symbols  modules.symbols.bin  source`

Similarly for `ls /usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-rc5+/` I get an `include` folder.

From these I have a suspicion that somehow the headers are broken (?), but I'm not sure how to proceed, what to check. If possible I would like to avoid rebuilding the kernel.

Comment: Please, show us `ls -l /lib/modules/5.6.0-rc5+/build` output and `lsb_release -a; uname -a` too. Is it kernel from the ubuntu or it was custom compiled by somebody and added into ubuntu? (They may incorrectly install headers.) Where did you download you OS image to use on this micro PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you use some experimental kernel like from https://github.com/avafinger/bananapi-zero-ubuntu-base-minimal

> v32 mailine kernel 5.6.0-rc5 (experimental) Ubuntu 19.10 EOAN

It was custom compiled for your board, and if you can't build kernel modules it seems to be not fully installed into the image either by you or by image author. 
(`ls -l /lib/modules/5.6.0-rc5+/build` or `ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` may help to debug this issue.)

You may try:

- contact image author to get hints of kernel-headers installation for module compilation; (he did publish linux-image deb file but not headers deb file in https://github.com/avafinger/bananapi-zero-ubuntu-base-minimal/releases/tag/v3.2)
- switch to some other kernel version with more correct installation package;
- or recompile the kernel (if image author has public scripts for building) and install it correctly. Actually manual install will probably just point the `build` directory to the directory where your kernel were built.

His https://github.com/avafinger/bananapi-zero-ubuntu-base-minimal/releases/tag/v3.2 - linux-image-5.6.0-rc5+_1.0-41.deb is not fully packaged, the `build` is just a symlink into his local directory which is not included into released deb file:

```
$ dpkg-deb -c ~/Downloads/linux-image-5.6.0-rc5+_1.0-41.deb |grep build
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2020-03-10 02:10 ./usr/lib/modules/5.6.0-rc5+/build -> /arm/ubuntu/cubieboard2/linux-5.6.y
```

PS: You already did contact him: https://github.com/avafinger/bananapi-zero-ubuntu-base-minimal/issues/34

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I solved the problem. I've built the version 5.6.0-rc7, with modules, and headers. I've installed the image, dtb, header, and lib. Now the ```ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build``` is accessible, and I could generate my .ko file. But for some reason my wlan0 is not present, and I cant start it - I guess I have to do some more digging. Either way that problem is not really related to the headers. Thank you!